# How to take the gradients of the center loss function described in tensorflow openface ?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, convolution, face-recognition, loss

I have read the paper that has mentioned the new loss function which adds more discriminative property for the classifier. This is the link 
http://ydwen.github.io/papers/WenECCV16.pdf
In the equation 3 they have mentioned how to take the gradients of the center variable w.r.t the loss. But it's not very clear how they did it.

Comment: Its done here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40162361/how-to-implement-center-loss-and-other-running-averages-of-labeled-embeddings